# Does YapDatabase have an equivalent to NSFetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, yapdatabase

I have a `UITableView` that uses a `YapDatabaseView` and a `YapDatabaseViewMappings`. I am trying to programmatically have my table view scroll to the position of a given object in the database...

With CoreData I was doing:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:myObject];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```

Any equivalent to that scenario with `YapDatabase`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does. You can use the API `indexPathForKey(:inCollection:withMappings)` which is available on `YapDatabaseViewTransaction`.

e.g.

```
YapDatabaseViewTransaction *viewTransaction = [transaction ext:"view name"];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [viewTransaction indexPathForKey(myObject.key, inCollection: myObject.collection, withMappings: mappings];
```

This assumes that you can access the key and collection from your object.

If you're using Swift, then check out [TaylorSource](http://github.com/danthorpe/taylorsource) which makes this a [doddle](https://github.com/danthorpe/TaylorSource/blob/development/framework/TaylorSource/YapDatabase/YapDB.swift#L157).